# C# Does Not Recognize 'dd-MMM-yyyy' as Valid Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-5

I have a function in a C# project that accepts a date as a string in the format 'dd-MMM-yyyy', so an example would be '10-MAR-2021'.

I need to convert that string into a datetime object, but everything I try results in

> String '10-‎Mar-2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have tried

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startdate);
```

And they all throw the same error. This was not a problem in .Net 4.6, however since upgrading to .Net 5 that date format is a problem all of a sudden.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this for a system that is in a `en-US` culture?

Comment: `dd-MMM-yyyy` works for me. When I copied your line of code there was a space before the hyphen, though.

Comment: I'm in Canada, but US formats usually work. As for the hyphen must be a copy/paste thing, there's no space in my code. As I mentioned it worked fine in .Net 4.6, but not in .Net 5

Comment: I changed my Region settings to Canada and Canadian English, and yes, there is such error... but then I had changed the InvariantCulture setting, so when putting it back it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some strange character inserted after the first dash. When I copy-paste the string "10-‎Mar-2021" returned in your exception, I get the same error.

Try

> char[] charArray = startdate.ToCharArray();

and debug. I get charArray[3] character with ASCII code 8206.

The code works for me when I don't copy-paste but write the startdate string myself.

Comment: You're right. When I create the string myself it works. The original string was coming from a datepicker, then passed through AJAX, so who knows what got thrown in there. Good catch!

Comment: U+200E (8206) is a left to right mark in general punctuation, [see Unicode-Table](https://unicode-table.com/de/200E/) or [Unicode chart pdf](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf)